# Is there any way to make this query a loop or more efficient?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a employee history table that contains the status date, status, and employee Id. The status dates are not on the same date and sometime could go for a couple of months without updating. I need to create a report creates a monthly snapshot of the employee's statuses each month.

Currently I'm selecting the max status date that's prior to month start of sysdate and repeating this query by subtracting a month at a time from the query, then doing a union to combine all of it.

```
SELECT id, 
       status_date, 
       status, 
       (trunc(sysdate, 'month')) AS Activity_Month
FROM empl_hist as e1 join
    (SELECT id, max(status_date) AS max_date, status_date FROM empl_hist 
     WHERE status_date <= (trunc(sysdate, 'month')) e2 
        on e1.id = e2.id and e1.status_date = e2.status_date

UNION ALL

SELECT id, 
    status_date, 
    status,
    (trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'month')) AS Activity_Month,
FROM empl_hist as e1 join
    (SELECT id, max(status_date) AS max_date, status_date FROM empl_hist 
     WHERE status_date <= (trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1), 'month')) e2 
        on e1.id = e2.id and e1.status_date = e2.status_date
```

I need this report for the past 24 months and it seems there should be a much better way of doing this rather than doing 23 Unions.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: That is an invalid query. `e2.status_date` does not exist. Did you intend `e2.max_date`?

Comment: Sorry, corrected that error

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a recursive query to generate your reporting months, then join that to  your empl_hist table and use aggregate functions to get the desire results:

```
WITH REPORT(ACTIVITY_MONTH) AS (
   SELECT CAST(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'month'),-24) AS DATE)
     FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
   SELECT CAST(ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVITY_MONTH,1) AS DATE)
     FROM REPORT
    WHERE ADD_MONTHS(ACTIVITY_MONTH,1) < SYSDATE
)
SELECT eh.id
     , max(eh.status_date) status_Date
     , max(eh.status) keep (dense_rank first order by status_date desc) status
     , r.activity_month
  FROM REPORT r
  JOIN EMPL_HIST EH
    ON EH.STATUS_DATE <= r.ACTIVITY_MONTH
 group by eh.id, r.activity_month
```

Comment: Plus one for popularizing `Recursive Subquery Factoring`, even if it makes more than twice lines than the *classical* `conenct by level` aproach

Comment: Thanks `connect by level` used to be undocumented, so labeled use at your own risk, I don't know if that's still the case.  Either way when `Recursive Subquery Factoring` was added to Oracle I made the switch.

Answer (score 1):

You may make the join with the *calendar* table (table containig you 24 reporting months) more effective, if you in the first step calculates the validity interval, i.e. the last day (inclusive) on which the status is valid - `status_date_to`.

The proposed calculation is valid if the `status_date` is truncated , i.e. without time.

*Use `status_date - interval '1' second`  instead of `status_date - 1` if there is a time component*.

Than you join only those records in the `EPML_HISTORY` that *match* with the reporing_month, i.e. `c.reporting_month between h.status_date and h.status_date_to`

```
WITH calendar AS (
SELECT  trunc(add_months(sysdate, 1-level), 'MM') reporting_month
FROM    dual
CONNECT BY level <= 24
), hist as (
SELECT id, 
       status_date,
       nvl(lead(status_date-1) over (partition by id order by status_date),add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'),1)) as status_date_to,
       status
from empl_hist)
select REPORTING_MONTH, ID, STATUS
from calendar c
join hist h on c.reporting_month between h.status_date and h.status_date_to
order by id, reporting_month;

REPORTING_MONTH             ID STATUS    
------------------- ---------- ----------
01.05.2018 00:00:00          1 active    
01.06.2018 00:00:00          1 active    
01.07.2018 00:00:00          1 active    
01.08.2018 00:00:00          1 active    
01.09.2018 00:00:00          1 deactive  
01.10.2018 00:00:00          1 deactive  
01.11.2018 00:00:00          1 deactive  
01.12.2018 00:00:00          1 deactive  
01.01.2019 00:00:00          1 active    
01.08.2018 00:00:00          2 active    
01.09.2018 00:00:00          2 active    
01.10.2018 00:00:00          2 active    
01.11.2018 00:00:00          2 deactive  
01.12.2018 00:00:00          2 deactive  
01.01.2019 00:00:00          2 deactive  
01.01.2019 00:00:00          4 active
```

Note also, you should possible revisit your logik of assigning the *reporting month* with `status_date <= (trunc(sysdate, 'month')`. In the sample data below the `id=3` is ignored, because it was activated on 5th of the current month, but `id=4` is reported because it was active on 1st of the current month.

**Sample Data**

```
drop table empl_hist;
create table empl_hist(
id number,
status_date date,
status varchar2(10));

insert into empl_hist values(1,DATE'2018-05-01','active');
insert into empl_hist values(1,DATE'2018-08-05','deactive');
insert into empl_hist values(1,DATE'2018-12-05','active');
insert into empl_hist values(2,DATE'2018-07-05','active');
insert into empl_hist values(2,DATE'2018-10-05','deactive');
insert into empl_hist values(3,DATE'2019-01-05','active');
insert into empl_hist values(4,DATE'2019-01-01','active');
```

Comment: This is a good solution, however, it potentially can lose data due to subtracting 1 from the activity_date and using a fully closed range.  e.g. if ID 6 has two records with the following dates `2018-09-30 08:30:00`, `2018-11-01 16:30:00`. In the first instance the `status_to_date` would be `2018-10-31 16:30:00` so would not get picked up for the November reporting period due to the fully closed range operator `BETWEEN` nor would the second. Instead use a semi-open range and don't subract 1 in the lead operation: `status_date <= reporting_month and reporting_month < status_to_date`

Comment: You are completely right @Sentinel, the proposed solution works only for truncated `DATE`s (as stated in the second sentence). For `DATE`s with time component you have to subtract `interval '1' second` to safely use the `BETWEEN` predicates. But of course you may switch to the *semi open* intervalls. Some purist would claim you should leave the last open interval on `NULL` and test is accordingly. This is a matter of taste and acceptance to write longer predicates;)

Comment: Thank you! Learned something new today. Never used connect by before.

Comment: @Bob check also the answer from Sentinel using *Recursive Subquery Factoring*

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a list of 24 months with a subquery and join that. Then I would use `row_number` to determine which is the most recent record within the window to avoid a self-join:

```
SELECT   id, status_date, status, Activity_Month
FROM     (
            SELECT     e.*,
                       m.Activity_Month,
                       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY m.Activity_Month 
                                          ORDER BY e.status_date DESC) rn
            FROM       (
                          SELECT  trunc(add_months(sysdate, 1-level), 'month') Activity_Month
                          FROM    dual
                          CONNECT BY level <= 24
                       ) m
            INNER JOIN empl_hist e
                    ON e.status_date <= m.Activity_Month
         ) base
WHERE    rn = 1
ORDER BY Activity_Month
```